# Unable to pass custom method to ElapsedEventHandler() as an argument

Tags: c#, windows-services, parameter-passing, directoryinfo

I am working on a windows service which will look for backup files in a particular folder. When it finds one the service will move all the backup files from that location and move them to an archived folder.

I have used `FileSystemWatcher` before but since it doesn't work on Servers I am using `DirectoryInfo` to look for the files.

The requirement is to run this service at every 5 minutes interval to look for any new backup files coming in.

I am stuck with the timer implementation.

### Following is my code:

I want to call `MoveToProcessed(processed)` method from the ElapsedEventHandler. but I am getting error **CS0149 - Method name expected**.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(backupdirectory);

    // Other unrelated code omitted

    // Move all the Backup files to Processed folder at certain intervals.
    createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    //***** ERROR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE *****
    createOrderTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MoveToProcessed(processed));
    //***************************************

    createOrderTimer.Interval = 300000; // 15 min
    createOrderTimer.Enabled = true;
    createOrderTimer.AutoReset = true;
    createOrderTimer.Start();
}

private void MoveToProcessed(string processed)
{
    // Code here backs up and restores files
}
```

Comment: `createOrderTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15).TotalMilliseconds;` may be slightly more readable (and therefore not require a comment).

Comment: Also, setting `Enabled = true` is the same as calling the `Start()` method, so you can remove one of those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily call a method *from* an event handler, but the event handler method itself must match a specific signature. For the `System.Timers` class, it should look something like this:

```
private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

So you can simply create a method with this signature, assign it as an event handler, and then call your method from there:

```
// Elapsed event handler calls our other method
private static void CreateOrderTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Not sure what the string argument represents, or how it should be set
    MoveToProcessed("some string");
}

// We can assign the event handler above when creating the Timer:
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15).TotalMilliseconds,
        AutoReset = true
    };

    createOrderTimer.Elapsed += CreateOrderTimer_Elapsed;
    createOrderTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, seems like I wasn't sure about the usage of EventHandler. It worked. The `processed` is just the path of Archive Directory as string.

Comment: I have another issue related to this question. 1. I wanted to make the First iteration instantly after the service is run i.e Pick up the file immediately after the service is started and not wait specified time `Interval = TimeSpan.ForMinutes(15).TotalMilliseconds`, but after the first time the interval should follow. 2. Also, How do I make the service in such a way that it doesn't look for the file unless the it has all it's processes.

Comment: You can call `MoveToProcess` just before (or after) you start the timer so it runs one right away. Not sure what you mean by "look for the file". You might want to ask that as a different question if your searching hasn't yielded an answer.

Comment: Thanks, calling `MoveToProcess` just after the interval worked. There were typos in my 2nd point. I wanted to say that, I don't want the Service to Look for New files unless it has completed (Restoring Database + Executing the Stored Procedure) where the storedProcedure might take longer than 6 hours to finish.

Comment: Restoring and calling the SP is the main functionality of my Service.